# The Ubuntu installer can't see the Windows 8 partition during installation

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows-8

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 8, but when I get to the installation type screen I don't have any option for installing alongside Windows 8. Ubuntu says I have no other operating systems and my partitions appear as free space. What can I do?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/44179

Answer (score 0):

Maby try to shrink your partions in windows 8 and install ubuntu on that partion. Totaly save normal.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/

Running ubuntu 12.10 / windows 8 on toshiba satellite C660

Comment: made a new partion but still cant see it in ubuntu installer

Comment: Install ubuntu on that partion using advanced installation available on the installer normal. Are you sure you did nothing unusual with your windows installation?